# How set default style for custom TextInputLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I want to create au custom TextInputLayout with a default style. But the style isn't applied.

```
class AutoCompleteTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = R.style.AppTheme_TextInputLayout_DropdownMenu
): TextInputLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        context.inflater.inflate(R.layout.auto_complete_text_input_layout, this,true) 
    }

}
```

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInputLayout.DropdownMenu" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="endIconMode">dropdown_menu</item>
</style>
```

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</merge>
```

I don't want this style to be applied by default for all TextInputLayout because I have already one like below:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <item name="textInputStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout</item>>
    </style>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the constructor with `R.style.AppTheme_TextInputLayout_DropdownMenu` because the **3rd** parameter of the `TextInputLayout` **isn't a style** but the attribute theme as **`R.attr.textInputStyle`**.

You can use something like:

```
public class AutoCompleteTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, 
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null, 
        defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.textInputStyle
) : TextInputLayout(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.Custom_Theme),
                    attrs, defStyleAttr) { ...  }
```

with a custom theme:

```
<style name="Custom.Theme" parent="">
   <item name="textInputStyle">@style/AppTheme.TextInputLayout.DropdownMenu</item>
</style>
```

In this way you are creating a new context wrapper with the specified theme (`Custom.Theme`). This theme is **used only by** the custom widget `AutoCompleteTextInputLayout`.
It means that the other `TextInputLayout`s continue to use the default style (defined by the attribute `textInputStyle` in the `AppTheme`).

Example:

```
<AutoCompleteTextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText/>

</AutoCompleteTextInputLayout>

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. But if I set this style in my custom theme, it will be applied by default for all InputLayout and I have already another one.

Comment: @Louis it is not your AppTheme. It is just a theme applied only to your `AutoCompleteTextInputLayout` with the `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Comment: if I replace @JvmOverloads by three constructor, it works... It's weird. Do you know why ?

Comment: @Louis I've tried the code in the answer and it works. Not sure where is your bug. Which version of kotlin are you usign?